# How to set target VM for an Azure loadbalancer inbound NAT rule with Ansible-azure?

Tags: azure, ansible

I need to create an inbound nat rule on my loadbalancer to redirect a certain port to a virtual machine. I've created my loadbalancer like so. I'm on Ansible 2.9.6.

```yaml
- name: Create loadbalancers
  azure_rm_loadbalancer:
    resource_group: "{{ item.lb_resource_group }}"
    name: "{{ item.lb_name }}"
    frontend_ip_configurations: "{{ item.lb_frontend_ip_configurations }}"
    backend_address_pools: "{{ item.lb_backend_address_pools }}"
    probes: "{{ item.lb_probes }}"
    load_balancing_rules: "{{ item.lb_load_balancing_rules }}"
    inbound_nat_rules: "{{ item.lb_inbound_nat_rules }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ lbs }}"
    tags:
      - lb
```

The inbound nat-rule looks like this.

```yaml
- name: "nat-rule-in"
  backend_port: 821
  protocol: Tcp
  frontend_port: 380
  frontend_ip_configuration: "lb-frontend"
```

I've looked in [this documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/azure_rm_loadbalancer_module.html) and can not find anything that says something about this. Is it not possible to set a target VM for an inbound nat-rule using Ansible or do I need to do it somewhere else?

I've also searched [the VM documentation for Ansible-azure](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/azure_rm_virtualmachine_module.html) but can't find anything related to NAT rules there either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems as if this really isn't an option with Ansible-azure itself.

I instead used the Azure-CLI with an SPN and ran the command through Ansible using `command`.

```sh
$ sudo apt-get install azure-cli
```

Within Ansible I used the code below to set the target VM after creating the inbound nat rule.

```yaml
- name: Create inbound NAT rules
    command: az network nic ip-config inbound-nat-rule add --ip-config-name <name>  --resource-group <name> --lb-name <name> --nic-name <name> --inbound-nat-rule <name>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to find is not the `azure_rm_virtualmachine` module in Ansible, it should be the `azure_rm_networkinterface` module. You can configure the [`ip_configurations`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/azure_rm_networkinterface_module.html#parameter-ip_configurations) property of the `azure_rm_networkinterface` to set the `load_balancer_backend_address_pools`, this property can associate the VM to the Load Balancer.

Comment: That's not it, that's what you use to add the IP addresses to the loadbalancer itself. What I'm trying to do is create a NAT rule within a loadbalancer, which works but I can't set the target VM for the NAT rule. I've circled the option I'm looking for in [this image](https://prnt.sc/wi3ac2).

Comment: @rpm192 I also met the issue before. You need to change the VM ip_configuration manually.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with az cli ...
It costed me a lot of time, glad I found this page. Indeed the way to (currently still) link the NAT rule to a backend is via the ipconfig object of the nic of the VM. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/nic/ip-config/inbound-nat-rule?view=azure-cli-latest